# Susy not importing into compass project

Tags: susy-compass

Been on the rides for a while.  Seen a lot of the same issues with everything from install: gem install compass --pre to fix your path in grunt.

Im using Fedora 24 and it does not seem to have any issues.  Gem update works with no errors.

My gem version from the cli $ gem list:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.8)
breakpoint (2.7.0)
chunky_png (1.3.6)
compass (1.0.3)
compass-core (1.0.3)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
did_you_mean (1.0.2, 1.0.0)
ffi (1.9.14)
io-console (0.4.6, 0.4.5)
json (2.0.2, 1.8.3)
multi_json (1.12.1)
power_assert (0.3.0)
psych (2.1.0, 2.0.17)
rake (11.2.2, 10.4.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
rb-inotify (0.9.7)
rdoc (4.2.2)
sass (3.4.22)
sassy-maps (0.4.0)
susy (2.2.12)
test-unit (3.2.1, 3.2.0)
```

Sass works fine.  Compass works fine.

I use Vim with syntastic installed when I open my manifest scss file I get this error:

> || File to import not found or unreadable: susy. Load paths:
>   /home/s/.gem/ruby/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets
>   Compass::SpriteImporter on line 4 o    f _grids.scss from line 4 of
>   style.scss Use --trace for backtrace.

from the cli: gem which susy

```
/home/s/.gem/ruby/gems/susy-2.2.12/lib/susy.rb
```

from my config.rb file:

```
    1 require 'compass/import-once/activate'
    2 # Require any additional compass plugins here.
    3 require "susy"
    4 
    5 # Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
>>  6 http_path = "/"
>>  7 css_dir = "stylesheets"
>>  8 sass_dir = "sass"
>>  9 images_dir = "images"
>> 10 javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
   11 
   12 # You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
   13 # output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed
   14 
   15 # To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
   16 # relative_assets = true
   17 
   18 # To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
   19 # line_comments = false
   20 
   21 
   22 # If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
   23 # project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
   24 # preferred_syntax = :sass
   25 # and then run:
   26 # sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
```

the >> flagged errors are for assigned but unused variables. Pretty sure that's not the problem.

From what I can tell, none of the old posts apply as versions installed are beyond anything already mentioned and I'm not using rails, grunt, etc.

Its pretty obvious that the paths aren't working but I don't see how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: What does the import look like in your Sass code? What's on line 4 of _grids.scss, and what's on line 4 of style.scss? (You should also know that Compass is officially End-of-Life, and no longer supported. May be time to look for an alternative.)

Comment: Hi Miriam,  my include on line 4 of _grids.scss is @import "susy";  with a space between import and "susy".  This works fine when I put the contents of the susy download scss file in the scss file of my project.  So I have it working as a hack.  Also had the same issue with breakpoint with the same work-around.

Comment: forgot style.scss question: line 4 is @import "grids"; which is working as a result of the manual import.  Sort of makes all the install this, install that look like joke.  I mean, doing it that way you don't worry about version control with respect to future changes.  Still would like to get it working.  In other words, not seeing a down side with the cut and paste:  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, everything you have there looks right to me. I don't really understand the ins-and-outs of Compass as a package manager (I worked on the Sass files), and the project is no longer supported, so I won't be much help. I feel like I've seen similar issues resolved on both the Compass and Susy Github issues. I'd start by looking there.

Comment: MIriam, thank you so much for the reply.  Did not know compass no longer maintained.  Self-taught, just learning.  Was trying to use compass, sass and susy.  What would you recommend for browser prefixes, and sprites going forward?  That and Yeoman, Gulp or Grunt?

Comment: I recommend auto-prefixer for prefixing. I don't know about sprites, or the other questions, sorry.